# Build modal content only when modal is opened

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

To speed loading of a large page of data, I am not loading images. I then list the items (classmate publications). What I want to do is have a modal trigger on each item in the list which will open a modal and pull in all the publication data, including images. But I don't want this text/images in the modal structure within the HTML, which would defeat the whole purpose. Instead, I want to only pull this from the server when the modal is opened. I have been looking at AJAX options, but was wondering if there is a simpler way. I have tried loading=lazy on my images, without much change in load time. (Loading the page with images takes significantly longer than loading it w/o, as one would expect.)
I am using javascript (not JQuery) and php, plus basic HTML/CSS.
I am open to all sorts of creative solutions.

Calling a php function doesn't change the content of the generated HTML file. I have considered changing the clickable icon (which currently loads the modal) to instead load a php page, but would then have to configure it to appear w/in the modal rather than replacing the existing page.
I have seen some answers using Bootstrap Modals, but I am not using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a modal component (maybe just a div tag with some p/span and img elements inside) which you show/hide in response to the user clicking an element of your list.

The function that handles the opening can set the innerHTML / src values so the images are loaded only when requested.

JS

```
const modalElement = document.querySelector(".modal")
const titleElement = document.querySelector(".modal__title")
const imageElement = document.querySelector(".modal__img")

const handleElementClick = (index) => {
    modalElement.classList.add("show");
    titleElement.innnerHTML = titleDict[index];
    imageElement.src = imagesDict[index];
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
     ...
     <li click="handleElementClick(1);">Element Name</li>
     ...
</ul>

...

<div class="modal">
    <p class="modal__title"><p>
    <img src="" alt="" class="modal__img" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should load only the text(html) content without the image. For every element, add a div and id which would later be used to load the image. So when the use clicks/trigger the element, the image is loaded from the server in respect to the image id, after which server per the image id returns the image source, then ajax implement the element to the modal.

**Example usage**

```
<div class="card"><div class="content-without-image">Welcome to my website. I was loaded without my image. If you need to see my image, you just click on the button below.</div><button onclick="load_the_image(image_id)">Click here to see image</button></div>

//<script>
function load_the_image(image_id){$.ajax({url:'url-to-server?image_id=' + image_id,method:'get',success:function(image_element_from_server){$('#card').append(image_element_from_server);}});}
```

**How it works**
On first page load, the image is not included in the element for faster page load. After user click on button, the function to get the image with the image id is triggered. The server receives the request, check if the image with the id exist. If exists, it response with `<image src="image_url"/>`. The JavaScript/frontend append the image to the modal for viewing by the user.
Hope this at least, give an idea.

Lemme know in the comment section if you need more help. Thanks

Comment: Mac, Thanks for the response. I understand the concept, and am pretty good with HTML, JavaScript, PHP. It looks like your function uses JQuery, which I do not use, and I am inexperienced with AJAX. I like Jose's answer because it seems pretty simple. What I would really like to do, however, is load the modal text, but only add in the image when the Modal is opened. I think I can figure it out from here as I have mastered opening modals with JavaScript since I posted the question. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, but I recommend you should try and lean jQuery too. It's easy than you'd thought trust me. You'll write short code for large work.

Comment: I have no doubt that it is easy to learn. I like to minimize the number of libraries I link to and, as an old retired guy who does this for fun (for my college class and several other groups), coming up with interesting ways to code things is what makes it fun. If this was a real job, I would feel differently!

Comment: Okay, that's cool